# Lagrangian mechanics beginner

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, education

Im a first year student of physics.
Because of coronavirus we have got online lessons, but my mechanic's lecturer doesn't like us, he didn't explain anything, just give us a problems to solve. 
I've got Landau-Lifshitz's book, but I even don't have enough caculus, to understand everything there. 
(there is the first and last equation, without derivation, I dont have even partial derivative in lessons [ofc., I learned it in my own, its not too bad, but Landau is still difficult]). 
Can you recommend me anything, that can help?

Comment: Are you taking advanced calculus simultaneously? If not drop this course and take advanced calculus.

Comment: Yes, ast semester I ended with single integrals. Now I've got second semester calculus, we just started partial derivative last week. I know, that's not good plan, but I can't choose a coutses, I have a plan in advance.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for some easier materials, who can explain mathematics in Landau.

Comment: @LillaMy : perhaps trying something that does not jump into Lagrangian Mechanics straightway may help. Taylor's book on classical mechanics, or Thornton and Marion come to mind.

Comment: Thank you so much. :))